# overwriting values in dataframe in python

Tags: python, loops, pandas, replace, dataframe

I'm new to python so this might seem a bit easy problem for you expertise.

I've 6 categories(0 to 5),each of which has 4 sub-categories namely: '3','4','5','6'.

for this,I've created a dataframe using:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=list(range(5)),columns=list([3,4,5,6])
```

Now,I'm getting some calculated values from my loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in list([3,4,5,6]):
       somecalculation=a
```

Now,I'm trying to replace the values of df with these calculations
like for second iteration (i.e. `for i=0,j=4`), I got `somecalculation=b`, for third s`omecalculation=c` and  further d.
When loop again iterates over `i=2`,I get calculations as e,f,g,h and so on for further iterations.
I'm trying to append these values to df as soon as I obtain them but I'm not getting the desired output as

```
  3 4 5 6 
0 a b c d
1 e f g h
2 i j k l
.........
.........
.........
```

because ultimately,I want to take average of the column values using their indices, but replacing values of dataframe is becoming troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your suggestion of appending to DataFrame rows iteratively is not optimal. it will slowdown the code. instead you can append the output to a list and than reshape the list as you like and ultimately convert it to pd.DataFrame. that will be way faster than what you propose. for example:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
list1=[] #initialize the list
list1.extend([i]) #where i is the output from your loop
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(list1,(5,4)),columns=['a','b','c','d']) # finally you can reshape the list as desired (eg: 5 row X 4 cols) and write it to dataframe in a single step
```

if this helps please do not forget to accept it:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but there are multiple ways to insert a value to a desired dataframe cell.

For example line,

```
df.xs(1)['e'] = x
```

inserts value x to a cell that has an index value of 1 and is in column 'e'.

If you wan't to calculate the mean of the certain column and insert that to spesific cell, you could do:

```
import numpy as np

df.xs(desired_index_value)['desired_column_name'] = np.mean(df.xs('col_x',axis=1))
```

Comment: I don't want to mention every time that I need to replace this or that value of the dataframe.I want my calculations to automatically replace the values of the df,once they are calculated in one iteration